# Juan berates her for her growing addiction [only for] Paula to rebuke him for selling crack to her in the first place.

Tags: grammar

Juan berates her for her growing addiction "only for" Paula to rebuke him for selling crack to her in the first place. could you please tell me why "only for" is used. what is the purpose of only for in the above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

*X only for Y*, where  X and Y are clauses, means that:

- X is supposed to have a consequence or effect,
- X completely failed,
- Y happened after X,
- The fact that Y happened proves that the attempt to do X failed spectacularly, made no sense, or was completely useless.